# PHP in XML - Parse error: Extra content at the end of the document

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

```
<no-ext-contact:identity type=\"Number\">

";

$clientFields = Client::find($userID)->customFieldValues;

foreach($clientFields AS $field)
{

if (isset($field->customField->fieldName)

and $field->customField->fieldName == "CustomFieldName") 

{   

$xml .=

$field->customField->value; // Add ID to XML    

}   

 else
{ 
    return ["error" => "Some Error Message"]; 
    }
}

$xml ="

</no-ext-contact:identity>
```

Between the xml section generates and error  Parse error: Extra content at the end of the document when getting value from database.

When I removes and have like a number everything works. So my question does the xml add or generates anything when gettings values from database? Or should I have it wrapped different to get it to work? Cant wrap my heads around this. Please advice.

Comment: I suspect that everything after $xml=" is defined as extra content.. so then it seems that its "finish the xml" instead of continue the xml.. if this make sense..

Comment: Not sure if this is your problem, but your last bit uses `$xml ="` and is probably missing the `.` to add the content - at the moment you are replacing the current content with just the close tag.